# Java CallableStatement getString, getInt, etc.?

Tags: java, callable-statement

I have some Java code that uses `CallableStatement`. I see that the code calls methods in `CallableStatement` named `getString`, `getInt`, etc. The `CallableStatement` itself invokes a database function (i.e. not s stored procedure).

I was wondering what exactly the `getString` and similarly named methods do and how they are used. From what I have read, they are used to get OUT parameters from a database function or stored procedure invocation, but I am not exactly sure how the whole thing works.

Comment: CallableStatement is an interface... You need a derived class to know how it actually works. OpenJDK is also open source, so go read the code. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/sql/CallableStatement.java#CallableStatement

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Sounds like what you have read is pretty much spot-on.  The `get...` methods let you retrieve the values of any OUT parameters of the stored procedure or function.